# /root/.bash_profile: No such file or directory

Tags: debian, servidor, aws, pip, cli

tengo que instalar aws cli y para eso requiere algo de `pip`, no entiendo muy bien que sea.

Siguiendo este tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_f0d2pLJjiA&t=133s al seguir todos los pasos tal cual me salio el siguiente error.

¿Alguien sabe a que se debe?, ya que a lo que leí debo de saber donde esta mi profile pero no se si este mal o bien; tomaré foto a lo que llevo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: en la primer línea tenes un error de tipeo es `export PATH` (pusiste `PATCH`)

Comment: uuhhh muchas gracias ¡¡¡